# After subsetting a dataset based on a condition in one column, how to combine/add data rows from original data sharing same value in another column?

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

For example, I have a dataset with several columns and rows:

```
final_summary <- data.frame(
sales_order = c("SO001","SO001","SO002","SO002","SO003","SO001","SO004", "SO005"),
person_name = c("Person A","Person B","Person A","Person C","Person A", "Person B","Person B","Person C"),
service_type = c("New Build", "Rebuild", "Reorder", "Rebuild", "New Build", "Reorder", "Reorder", "New Build"),
product_type = c("Material B", "Material D", "Material D", "Material A", "Material C", "Material A", "Material A", "Material C")
                 )
```

I can subset this data based on "New Build" in "service_type" variable (data_1 shown below), but I want to add more data rows that matches the same sales order ID listed in the "data_1" even though they may have a different service type etc.

Basically I want the final dataset to be a combination of sorts shown in the image attached while keeping the same variables and preferably sorted by "sales_order" (I know how to do this via select and group_by functions). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
data_1 <- subset(final_summary, final_summary$service_type == "New Build")
view(data_1)
```

[image: Final Dataset]

Comment: I edited the data object code to show how to avoid littering your workspace with unnecessary items. It aids in avoiding problems with naming conventions accidentally pulling in named objects when what was originally intended was that you were using column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final_summary %>%
    filter(sales_order %in% sales_order[service_type == "New Build"]) %>%
    arrange(sales_order)
```

Comment: thank you so much this is exactly what I needed. the %in% was what I was blanking on

Answer (score 1):

since `final_summary$sales_order[final_summary$service_type == "New Build"]` will have those `sales_oder` where your condition is met, you can simply replace your condition by filtering those sales_order where these are `%in%` of above result.  baseR way

```
subset(final_summary, sales_order %in% sales_order[service_type == "New Build"])

  sales_order person_name service_type product_type
1       SO001    Person A    New Build   Material B
2       SO001    Person B      Rebuild   Material D
5       SO003    Person A    New Build   Material C
6       SO001    Person B      Reorder   Material A
8       SO005    Person C    New Build   Material C
```

Comment: much appreciated. the %in% was what I was missing